# Parse string to DateTime in C# mimicking behavior of SQL Server CAST/CONVERT

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime-format

I'm working with a database containing date time values stored as strings in various different formats. These values are obtained from different external sources and their formats are outside my control. It may be possible to enumerate all formats currently stored in the database, but some as-yet-unseen format may show up at some point in the future.

In the past, these values were parsed to SQL DATETIME with SQL Server's CONVERT function and then returned to a .NET application. Now the application is receiving the string instead and parsing has to take place there.

I initially used DateTime.Parse(), but that failed because it didn't handle some formats which SQL Server handles by default (such as "yyyyMMdd"). The next approach was to use the DateTime.TryParseExact overload that takes a string array for various formats. Something like:

```cs
var dateTimeString = "20210101";
var dateTimeFormatInfo = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
var expectedDateTimeFormats = dateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns().ToList();
expectedDateTimeFormats.Add("yyyyMMdd");

DateTime.TryParseExact(dateTimeString, expectedDateTimeFormats.ToArray(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces, out var myDateTime);
```

This works except that it also doesn't handle certain formats, like "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss.mmm", which SQL Server handles by default. Ironically that particular example is also handled fine by DateTime.Parse().

Is there a good way to mimic the behavior of SQL Server's CONVERT(DATETIME, val) in C# to try and successfully parse at least as many formats as were being handled in the original solution where the conversion was done in the database?

I think a solution with ParseExact that includes all the formats listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) may work but I'm wondering if there's a better way. Or maybe a better approach altogether.

Comment: If SQL Server handles these formats by default, would it be possible to actually ask SQL Server to do the conversion for you, before giving you the data?

Comment: You **need** to know what format the input is before attempting conversion. Otherwise you risk ambiguities and errors. `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the proper format string does support all those supported by SQL Server (and more), so it'll be fine.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen reverting to the old behavior is technically possible, but I am required to do this on the application instead. The idea is that the code will be more maintainable this way, if we can replicate the behavior.

Comment: @Alejandro unfortunately I just can't guarantee I'll know what all the formats are. I think ensuring that we cover the formats that SQL CONVERT handles is sufficient in this case.

Comment: @CristianSanchez Then you can guarantee correct behavior and your code will soon or later break or give wrong results. Just supporting the all the formats isn't enough (you can easily do that in any language), **it's a MUST** to know which one you're using for every single case. As an example, if you have the string "03021203", can you say which date is it without further context? It could be February 3rd, 1203, or March 2nd, 1203, or December 3rd, 302, I have no idea. Most likely, blindy using `CONVERT` in SQL Server without any other info will also result in broken code

Comment: The code might be more maintainable this way but if maintainability was a concern, why the he.. did someone opt to store dates as strings in the first place?

Comment: I agree with both of you. This is definitely not an ideal situation. At the end of the day, though, there's only so much I can control. If I didn't have any constraints I'd probably normalize the data as it comes in and store it properly at that stage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** [@jeroen-mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert)'s comment about using `SqlDateTime.Parse` is probably a better answer than what what we wound up going with.

Original answer:

In case it helps anyone in the future, the answer wound up being to use DateTime.TryParse() and, if that failed, calling DateTime.TryParseExact() with the special formats not already supported by TryParse().

From glancing over the source code it seems that Parse/TryParse is more lenient about things like separators, such that it works even with similar formats that are not shown when enumerating dateTimeFormatInfo.GetAllDateTimePatterns(). I believe that explains why TryParseExact didn't seem to work with formats that TryParse supported, even when TryParseExact was using all the DateTime patterns provided by the DateTimeFormatInfo object.

I did also validate format support against the listed [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles) in Microsoft's docs. This solution doesn't support 100% of them, though. That is by design since some combinations can be non-deterministic, and we are thankfully confined to a specific culture.

Not a perfect solution, as pointed out in the comments, but it did the trick here.

Comment: Although there is no code in C# that will *exactly* replicate what SQL Server does (if for no other reason than that things like the 2-digit year cutoff are configurable, and so dependent on the server configuration) this solution seems to be a rehash of [`SqlDateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.parse), which also uses a fixed list of formats. As that's presumably been written with replicating SQL Server's logic in mind, you may prefer it to a roll-your-own.

Comment: The most offensive instances of conversion logic in SQL Server are (fortunately) not replicated this way, although there will be applications depending on them: `''` (the empty string) is converted (explicitly and implicitly) to the "zero" `DATETIME` `1900-01-01`, `2000` (just a year) is padded to `2000-01-01`, probably others I'm forgetting. I pity the folks who have to be bug-for-bug compatible.

Comment: Interesting. That does return an SqlDateTime object, where I'd need a plain DateTime, but it looks like SqlDateTime.Value returns the DateTime equivalent. That might've saved me some work if I'd known about it at the time 

Any chance you have a link to documentation outlining the supported string formats? I'm not seeing anything on the docs page you linked to and not finding much in a cursory web search.

Comment: There is no formal documentation of what it will parse (and that's true for *both* the class and SQL Server itself, actually), but there is [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDateTime.cs#L66). (Actual method entry [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Data.Common/src/System/Data/SQLTypes/SQLDateTime.cs#L346).)

Comment: Thank you! That looks very much like what we wound up doing, but you have a good point that it's likely better to use this than roll our own.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the schema of your database your could either create a View or a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15) on the Table with the [`FORMAT()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to format the dates in a standardized and single consistent format that C#'s DateTime can easily handle.

Please note that the `FORMAT()` function *can* be less-than performant compared to other native SQL Server functions, in certain contexts.

Comment: I suspect this may fall under the same category as reverting to the old behavior of simply doing the conversion on the database side, though I do like the idea.

The reason we are moving this out of the database to begin with is to allow for the parsing code to be more portable (in case the DB provider changes in the future) and more testable through unit tests, etc. If we went this route there would still be some dependency on the DB handling the formatting correctly and, as you pointed out, in a performant manner.

Comment: @CristianSanchez I hear ya, while I understand the incentive to decouple logical dependencies from the data layer, I'm personally not fully bought into it, nor have I ever had a reason to be concerned with the chances of changing database providers. Any context I've worked in, the chances of moving away from SQL Server were as likely as completely dropping the main language of the tech stack we were working in, C#, which means there really is no difference where one puts there dependencies then. I know most would disagree with me, and that's it's the majority thought otherwise in *theory*...

Comment: ...in *practice*, Id say the realistic need for being concerned to decouple that much from the database layer is less common than the modern developer realizes. But of course such a stance on either side is subjective to a degree, mine being driven from the fact in a quasi-DBA in addition to being a developer lol. All of that being said, I've found by living by the simple rule of letting the database solve data problems as being the most simplest and effective way I've solved many problems. Structuring and normalizing data is an ideal database problem, and probably makes sense to persist in...

Comment: ...in the database layer, which you can achieve with a **persisted computed column** too, which actually would be a plus for performance as well. But to each their own, that's just my opinion, sorry for the rant lol.